# Stand alone executable

Tags: vb.net, deployment, executable

I am working on a relatively simple program in VB.NET. I am trying to make the installation process as simple as possible for the user.

I know its possible to use the executable from the debug directory as a stand alone executable, but are there any drawbacks to this approach? For example, if the user does not have .NET on their machine, the program will not run.

Is there a way to publish the program so it is self-contained in a single executable file?

Thanks for help.

Comment: There must be a way to include dependent files as resources. I know it would bloat your stand-alone exe but it would be truly stand alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a ClickOnce deployment Executable is your closest bet to achieving this.
Here's a nice tutorial on how to do that: [ClickOnce Deployment](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm)

Comment: I like ClickOnce a lot, but since it has an "unusual" look to the installer, a lot of users will think it's shady or confusing. I even thought this the first time I tried it. Just consider that if you're releasing to the "masses".

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned Microsoft offers ILMerge but if you do not want to use a 3rd party application this is how you would code it yourself. Your client will still need the .Net Framework but it will allow you to hide your dependencies. If you want to include .Net dlls as well you must set your references to "copy local" in the references setting.

This program requires that you add your dll as a resource. Whenever your program requires that dll it will load it on demand by use of the assembly resolve hook. If you had multiple dlls you would have to have a switch case or a list look up that loaded the correct dll based upon ResolveEventArgs.Name.

```
Module Program
    ''//Entry Point add dependency resolver hook
    Sub Main()
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, _
                   AddressOf AssemblyReslover
    End Sub

    Private Function AssemblyReslover(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                  ByVal e As ResolveEventArgs) _
                                  As Assembly
       ''//ReferenceAssembly
        Dim ra As Assembly
        ra = Assembly.Load(My.Resources.MyDLL)
        Return ra
    End Function

End Module
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate Smart Assembly can compile a .NET assembly into a stand-alone executable. It can embed all dependencies into the executable.

It is not free, but it does come with other very useful tools. We have started using this recently and so far it has been pretty useful.

https://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/index.htm

Comment: Microsoft offers ILMerge for free: "ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output. See the accompanying documentation for details." - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en

Answer (score -1):

I don't think .NET programs can normally be made into standalone programs since the .NET framework is designed to be separate from the program. However, have you considered [installing the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542.aspx) during your installation using the distributable .NET package? That would make sure that the users have the latest version of .NET if they don't already.

(I've linked to the 2.0 package here, you may need a newer version.)